# How can I map tables using fluent API in ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create a one to one relationship using C# in Entity Framework 6 using ASP.NET MVC 5 with built-in user authentication.

I am able to make tables and connections with the defaults that Entity Framework creates. But when I try to use fluent API.... more specifically when I use on model creating even empty my database migration using the package manager console will fails. How can I map my one to one relationship?

My error:

```
//error
//my.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined.   //Define the key for this EntityType.
//my.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. //Define the key for this EntityType.
//IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type    //'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
//IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type //'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

My Code:

```
namespace my.Models
{

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<EngineeringProject> EngineeringProjects { get; set; }

        public DbSet<EngineeringProject> EngineeringDesigns { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EngineeringDesignMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EngineeringProjectMap());
        }

    }
}

namespace my.Models.Mapping
{
    public class EngineeringProjectMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EngineeringProject>
    {
        public EngineeringProjectMap()
        {
            this.HasRequired(t => t.EngineeringPd)
                .WithOptional(t => t.EngineeringProject);
            this.HasRequired(t => t.EngineeringProjectCategory)
                .WithMany(t => t.EngineeringProjects)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _has no key defined_ What's not clear to you? What does `IdentityUser` look like?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The errors occur because the derived identity tables have mapping in the derived context. This needs to be called inside the new OnModelCreating override function. To do this simply add base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) to your method as seen below.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // <-- This is the important part!
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EngineeringDesignMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EngineeringProjectMap());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are missing a call to `base.OnModelCreating` in your DbContext.